# How do you change the approval status back to Pending if an already approved document has been edited?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an approval workflow in a document library. It's manually started by the user because they may not want to start it everytime they edit a document.

The workflow is as follows:

```
If for UK
```

> Start approval process with John

```
Else if for US
```

> Start approval process with Diane then Jim

It works just fine so far, but if a user edits a document, it still shows as approved which it has not been since there were edits. I'm trying to figure out a solution so that when a user checks in a document that has been edited, the approval status changes back to Pending until it goes through one of the approval processes again.

Any ideas? I haven't been able to find a solution online anywhere or in any of my books.

Answer (score 0):

I assume while creating the workflow you have selected "Allow this workflow to be manually started by an authenticated user with Edit Item permissions.".

> Basically you are handling the OnItemAdded part.

In your existing workflow, you might have selected "Start this workflow when a new item is created."

> Simillarly, you also have to handle OnItemUpdated part

**Create a new workflow with same email sending conditions with option "Start this workflow when an item is changed."**

OR

```
You can modify the existing workflow to handle both Added & Changed scenarios.
```

Comment: I have the manual option checked, however, I don't have the "Start when new item is created" checked because I don't want it automatically started, ever.

I guess I could set up a new workflow so that when an item is edited, the approval status is set to Pending or null. Think that might work? Can I do that in SP Designer and not VS?

Comment: why dont you just add it to the existing workflow if edit return to step x?

Answer (score 0):

workaround

Create hidden column with name **ItemIdentifier**. default value empty

1. When workflow started, set **ItemIdentifier** value empty
2. check if **ItemIdentifier** is empty, if value is empty then set workflow status to **Pending**
3. When workflow is approved then set value of ItemIdentifier to **Approved**. Then set workflow status to **Approved**

Hence after workflow is approved and user edit the item then workflow status will be **Pending**